# Running short-term tasks via upstart

Tags: scripts, upstart

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Task: run script at certain start/stop conditions. No long-running service/daemon is launched, only short-term actions.

Upstart script test.conf:

```
description     "test script"

start on local-filesystems or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

task

pre-start exec /full/path/to/script.sh start
pre-stop exec /full/path/to/script.sh stop
```

Problems:

1. Running 'start test' never ends. If I Ctrl-C hanged upstart, furtehr 'status' calls show the service is running.'
2. 'stop test' doesn't result in running 'pre-stop' stanza at all.

Is the original task solvable using upstart scripts?

Thanks.

**Update.** "the fact that your script.sh has both start and stop actions, which does suggest a long-running daemon"

No contradiction. There's startup action and cleanup action, without long-running process(es) in between.

When I add 'exec' stanza, i.e.

```
exec /full/path/to/script.sh idle
```

the result is this:

```
$ start test
test stop/waiting

$ status test
test stop/waiting

$ stop test
stop: Unknown instance:
```

**Correction**: The script mentioned in stanzas is executed with 'start' and 'idle' parameters, but not with 'stop'.

Answer (score 3):

Your upstart config file lacks an `exec` or `script` section, and you seem to be wanting to start things with the pre-start command only, which is not correct. Per the upstart documentation (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html):

> All job files must have either an exec or script stanza. This
>   specifies what will be run for the job.
>
> Additional shell code can be given to be run before or after the
>   binary or script specified with exec or script. These are not expected
>   to start the process, in fact, they can't. They are intended for
>   preparing the environment and cleaning up afterwards.

Also, what your original task requests ("No long-running service/daemon is launched, only short-term actions.") seems to contradict the fact that your `script.sh` has both `start` and `stop` actions, which *does* suggest a long-running daemon.

```
description     "test script"

start on local-filesystems or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

task

# Assuming script.sh start starts, performs a process, and then exits,
# this should work
exec /full/path/to/script.sh start

# No need for a pre-stop
```

The upstart document I linked to is supposedly deprecated, you can also have a look at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/ which is a good reference and has useful examples, so I suggest you read it if things are still unclear.

Comment: (updated original post, sicne I needed formatting)

Comment: I updated the OP to reflect my comments.